# Private and protected @interface in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at a .h file for an Objective-C class and I see multiple interface declarations in it and I am unsure as to what the differences are and what they mean.

First I see

```
@interface TAModel : NSObject
```

Which I recognize.  TAModel is the class and NSObject is it's super class.  What I'm confused about is further down I see another interface declaration:

```
@interface TAModel (Protected)
```

Also inside another .m file (unrelated to the first two) I have seen:

```
@interface TAWorker (Private)
```

I was wondering what the second two mean, what they are doing.  As far as I know with objective-c there is no true protected visibility between classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a category class in which they're putting their protected/private members. The usual idiom is just to create a class extension (so you'll often see `@interface Foo ()`; the difference here is that you can also declare more fields, not just properties and methods) in the `.m` file.

Neither way of doing this truly protected or private as you can still technically get at the things declared there by casting to `id` first or through one of the `performSelector:` methods.  But it's pseudo-private because you don't publish the interface publicly if it's not in the .h file.

Comment: `@interface Foo ()` defines a class *extension*, not a category.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  The private and protected keywords in the parentheses don't actually make them private/protected, its more the fact that they are in the .h .m files right?  Is this an advisable way to go about this or you think there are better ways?

Comment: @strikerdude10 Right. What word you put in the parens makes no difference; it's just where you put the declaration. Generally I think  the class extension is a better way to go, as it gives you more flexibility with what you can do. There's nothing wrong with using categories, though.